I want to make the extra part of the cabinet and the width of the cabinet look the same


I want to attach the (selected) extra side on the (카운터. 001) with the (카운터. 003) *It means 카운터.001= counter.001, 카운터.003=counter.003, but it's actually a cabinet.I misused the term.
But I'm not sure what to do. 카운터.003 is the door of the upper cabinet and counter. 001 is the upper cabinet behind the door. To make a smooth top that doesn't stick out and can be opened without a handle, I want to make that extra side look the same as 003's width, and I want it to look like it's glued up, what should I do?


I solved it

